# Weld CDI on Google App Engine: Injection in servlet not happening

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-weld

This is my first time working with GAE and I'm trying to get CDI working. **Long story short: The `@Inject` field in my servlet is not getting injected (it's always `null`).**

I'm working in Eclipse and debug the application on the local test server included in the GAE SDK (which is started by Eclipse as well). When I access the servlet on `localhost`, I get a null-pointer exception for `someService`. I've also output the value of `someService` to verify it is really `null`, which it is.

**Edit:** When I added a `@Named("skldjfx")` qualifier to the injection point, Weld complained the dependency is unsatisfied (in the validation phase), so that's a good sign. However, the field is still always `null`.

Servlet:

```
public class BlogServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Inject private SomeService someService;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello. " + someService.getSomeValue());
        //                                      \
        //                                  always null
    }
}
```

`SomeService` class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeService {

    private String someValue = "some value";

    public String getSomeValue() {
        return someValue;
    }
}
```

I've configured Weld's `Listener` in `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The listener is properly loaded because it logs its initialization message: `org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener contextInitialized`.

I've included (an empty) `beans.xml` in both `war/WEB-INF` and `war/META-INF`. I also tried it without `META-INF`. **Maybe `beans.xml` isn't processed?** Other contents in the `WEB-INF` folder (such as `web.xml`) *are* processed properly.

How can I verify if `beans.xml` is processed and/or fix `SomeService` not getting injected?

Comment: Hi there, I am interested to know if it is still the case..? Is still CDI not available on Google App Engine (now, roughly 2 years later) ?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible to use CDI with GAE, because GAE's Jetty fork ignores `jetty-web.xml`, which is needed to specify the `BeanManager`. See [this link](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2943) and [this link](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3548). Really strange GAE is not supporting the use of CDI.

*Note that these links are really old, but so far I haven't found any evidence to the contrary.*

Anyway, my next step will be to use Google's own dependency injection framework Guice. Using it with GAE is described [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/GoogleAppEngine). I'd prefer CDI though.

Comment: If you're looking for a PaaS to try EE 6, take a look at Red Hat's OpenShift https://openshift.redhat.com/ There's also the open source version you can run on your own computer https://github.com/openshift

Comment: Meanwhile (late 2014) the linked feature requests at google have been forwarded to engineering. Let's hope they get implemented soon :)