# JSF applicaton on Google App Engine as backend to android application. Injected objects are null

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jsf, servlets

I have created a JSF application on Google App Engine to supply data for an Android application. I will use the JSF application to prepare data for and evaluate data from the Android application. I use Objectify and the Google Datastore for persistence.

Now I'm about to take the next step, and I'm in trouble :( 
I need to somehow download and upload data from the datastore to the android app. My first idea was to use an extra Servlet (not the Faces Servlet) inside the webapplication and let the servlet use the business logic (cdi beans).

There is no problem calling the servlet, but when I inject the cdi beans that works fine in the JSF application, they always are null. Injection works fine in every other part of the application, but in the extra servlet (I call it MobileServlet) the injected beans are always null.

Any suggestions? This is my first JSF application, so there it is very possible that I misunderstand something vital ;)

EDITED: Some of my files:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>GlideSpeedTester_cdi</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
  <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bluesky</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableThreading</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>MobileServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>MobileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>se.widmantiming.glidespeedtester.servlets.MobileServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MobileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MobileServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

beans.xml (in folder WebContent, same as web.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Injection that works:

```
package se.widmantiming.glidespeedtester.beans;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import se.widmantiming.glidespeedtester.dataservices.LoginService;
import se.widmantiming.glidespeedtester.entities.User;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {

    @Inject
    private SessionBean sessionBean;

    private String mUsername;
    private String mPassword;
    private String mConfirmedPassword;
    private String mFirstName;
    private String mLastName;
    private String mEmail;
    private String mTestTeamPassword;


    @Inject
    private LoginService loginService;

    public String login() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(mUsername);
        user.setPassword(mPassword);

        return login(user);

    }

    private String login(User user) {
        User u = loginService.login(user);
        if (u == null) {
            return "login";
        }
        sessionBean.setUser(u);
        return "main";
    }

    public String createAccount() {
        if (!mPassword.equals(mConfirmedPassword)) {
            return "create_account";
        }
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(mUsername);
        user.setPassword(mPassword);
        user.setFirstName(mFirstName);
        user.setLastName(mLastName);
        user.setEmail(mEmail);
        user.setActive(true);
        User u = loginService.createAccount(user, mTestTeamPassword);
        if (u == null) {
            return "create_account";
        }
        return "login";
    }


    public String logout() {
        sessionBean.setUser(null);
        return "login";
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return (sessionBean.getUser() != null);
    }

    public SessionBean getSessionBean() {
        return sessionBean;
    }

    public void setSessionBean(SessionBean sessionBean) {
        this.sessionBean = sessionBean;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return mUsername;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        mUsername = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return mPassword;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        mPassword = password;
    }

    public String getConfirmedPassword() {
        return mConfirmedPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmedPassword(String confirmedPassword) {
        mConfirmedPassword = confirmedPassword;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return mFirstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        mFirstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return mLastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        mLastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return mEmail;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        mEmail = email;
    }

    public String getTestTeamPassword() {
        return mTestTeamPassword;
    }

    public void setTestTeamPassword(String testTeamPassword) {
        mTestTeamPassword = testTeamPassword;
    }

    public LoginService getLoginService() {
        return loginService;
    }

    public void setLoginService(LoginService loginService) {
        this.loginService = loginService;
    }

}
```

Injection that does not work:

```
package se.widmantiming.glidespeedtester.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import se.widmantiming.glidespeedtester.beans.MobileBean;
import se.widmantiming.glidespeedtester.entities.GlideWaxType;
import se.widmantiming.glidespeedtester.entities.User;

public class MobileServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Injecting just to see if it is null
@Inject
private loginBean loginBean;

private String message = "Hello";

public void init() throws ServletException {

}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


    if (loginBean == null) {
        message = "Bean is null";
    }
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
}

public void destroy() {

}

public MobileBean getMobileBean() {
    return mobileBean;
}

public void setMobileBean(MobileBean mobileBean) {
    this.mobileBean = mobileBean;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public User getUser() {
    return mUser;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    mUser = user;
}
```

}

Comment: do you have any beans.xml on the locattion of the Servlet? If bean is null it looks like it's not discovered by CDI.

Comment: Yes, beans.xml is there. Is there any possibility that the extra Servlet doesn't find it? Now I have edited the question wtih some code.

Comment: The problem is that you are using Servlet 2, so you need to specify the servlet listener to boot Weld (CDI Implementation) in the web.xml. Or you can use `@WebServlet` annotation (Servlet 3.0) and you would not need extra configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to stick with servlet-2.5 since I use Google App Engine. Doesn't this part of my web.xml handle the booting of Weld? <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
  </listener>

Comment: Actually, it looks like it's not possible to use CDI in Servlet with Google App Engine, see this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405944/weld-cdi-on-google-app-engine-injection-in-servlet-not-happening

Comment: Thanks for your help! Should have found that link myself considering the amount of time I've spent on this ;) Will check it out, but I'm still confused why injection works for the faces servlet but not the other one...